# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que esta consulta, que funciona bien en DBeaver, funcione en java?

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, backend, aplicación-movil

Lo que hace esta consulta es que dependiendo del `Cliente_Id`, el cual está parametrizado, me debe traer la data almacenada, ya sea por 360 o 90 días, pero no está tomando la condición y siempre está trayéndolo por 360 días sin importar el `Cliente_Id` que ingrese.

Esta consulta funciona bien cuando la pruebo en el DBeaver, pero en java no está funcionando.

```java
querysEjec.addTable(
    "HIST_VALOR_PARTICIPACION",
    "HIST_VALOR_PARTICIPACION_ID,ASESOR_ID,CLIENTE_ID,EMPRESA_ID,MARCA_ID,"
    + "PUNTO_VENTA_ID,SEGMENTO_ID,VALOR,FECHA_EJECUCION",
    "SELECT \n"
    + "rownum AS HIST_VALOR_PARTICIPACION_ID,ASESOR_ID,\n"
    + "CLIENTE_ID,EMPRESA_ID,\n"
    + "MARCA_ID,PUNTO_VENTA_ID,SEGMENTO_ID,\n"
    + "VALOR, \n"
    + "FECHA_EJECUCION \n"
    + "FROM EJEC_PROG_PARTICIPACION \n"
    + "WHERE CLIENTE_ID = :CLIENTE_ID \n"
    //+ "AND FECHA_EJECUCION BETWEEN SYSDATE - 360 AND SYSDATE \n"
    + "AND FECHA_EJECUCION BETWEEN SYSDATE - ( CASE \n"
    + "WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PARAMETROS p WHERE VALOR LIKE '%'||:CLIENTE_ID||'%' \n"
    + "and p.nombre = 'HIST_PART_ANUAL') = 1 \n"
    + "THEN 360 \n"
    + "ELSE 90 \n"
    + "END \n"
    + ") AND SYSDATE \n"     
    + "AND PUNTO_VENTA_ID IN ( \n"
    + "SELECT UNIQUE \n"
    + "PUNTO_VENTA.PUNTO_VENTA_ID \n"
    + "FROM PUNTO_VENTA, RUTA_ASESOR_PV, BARRIO \n"
    + "WHERE RUTA_ASESOR_PV.PUNTO_VENTA_ID = PUNTO_VENTA.PUNTO_VENTA_ID \n"
    + "AND PUNTO_VENTA.BARRIO_ID = BARRIO.BARRIO_ID (+) \n"
    + "AND BARRIO.BARRIO_ID(+) = PUNTO_VENTA.BARRIO_ID \n"
    + "AND RUTA_ASESOR_PV.IND_ESTADO = 1 \n"
    + "AND PUNTO_VENTA.ESTADO_PUNTO_VENTA_ID = 1 \n"
    + "AND RUTA_ASESOR_PV.ASESOR_ID = :ASESOR_ID \n"
    + "AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN TRUNC(RUTA_ASESOR_PV.FECHA_CICLO_INICIO) AND TRUNC(RUTA_ASESOR_PV.FECHA_CICLO_FIN)) \n"
    + "ORDER BY FECHA_EJECUCION DESC",
    "ASESOR_ID,CLIENTE_ID"
);
```

Comment: En lugar de colocar una imágen con el código agrega el código directamente en tu pregunta.

Comment: gracias por la recomendación.

Comment: Revisa el código, tienes una nueva línea tras `WHERE VALOR LIKE ` sin haber cerrado las comillas y añadido un + para concatenar con la siguiente línea

Comment: hola, si no que al pegar el codigo no quedo  en orden pero esas dos lineas van juntas de esta forma   + "WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PARAMETROS p WHERE VALOR LIKE'%'||:CLIENTE_ID||'%' \n"

Comment: No es claro cómo usas esa consulta o cómo le entregas los parámetros que quieres que use

Comment: *Esta consulta funciona bien cuando la pruebo en el DBeaver, pero en java no está funcionando.* ¿Estás capturando los errores en Java? ¿Qué error obtienes? ¿O la consulta se ejecuta pero no hace lo esperado? Un eventual mensaje de error sería importante para tener una idea de lo que está ocurriendo, aparte de mostrar como vinculas los datos.

Comment: La consulta se esta ejecutando pero no hace lo esperado, deberia traerme la data de 360 dias o 90 dias dependiendo el CLIENTE_ID con el que ingrese, pero lo que esta haciendo es que me trae data anual para todos los Clientes_id